# How is if-statement and bitwise operations same in this example?

Tags: c, if-statement, bit-manipulation

I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/886669) and it is mentioned that this code;

```
if (data[c] >= 128)
    sum += data[c];
```

can be replaced with this one;

```
int t = (data[c] - 128) >> 31;
sum += ~t & data[c];
```

I am having hard time grasping this. Can someone explain how bitwise operators achieve what if statement does?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
if (data[c] >= 128)
    sum += data[c];
```

Clearly adds `data[c]` to `sum` if and only if `data[c]` is greater or equal than 128. It's easy to show that

```
int t = (data[c] - 128) >> 31;
sum += ~t & data[c];
```

Is equivalent (when `data` only holds positive values, which it does):

`data[c] - 128` is positive if and only if `data[c]` is greater or equal than 128. Shifted arithmetically right by 31, it becomes either all ones (if it was smaller than 128) or all zeros (if it was greater or equal to 128).

The second line then adds to `sum` either `0 & data[c]` (so zero) in the case that `data[c] < 128` or `0xFFFFFFFF & data[c]` (so `data[c]`) in the case that `data[c] >= 128`.

Answer (score 4):

`int t = (data[c] - 128) >> 31;
sum += ~t & data[c];`

> (Note that this hack is not strictly equivalent to the original
>   if-statement. But in this case, it's valid for all the input values of
>   data[].)

`(data[c] - 128) >> 31;` //this is trying to extract only the sign bit of data[c] when data[c] is greater than or equal to 128, if it is less than 128 then (data[c] - 128) will automatically shift into some negative number thus setting the sign bit.

and `sum += ~t & data[c];`
will AND the value data[c] with either 1 or 0 depending upon the complemented value of sign bit.Signifies nothing will be added to `sum` if value(`(data[c] - 128)`) is negative.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data[c] >= 128)
    sum += data[c];
```

is equal to

```
if (data[c] - 128 >= 0)
    sum += data[c];
```

which means that add `data[c]` to sum if `data[c] - 128` is not negative. So we need to extract sign of `data[c] - 128`. As data is 32bit int array. So for getting sign, we need to arithmetically shift it `32 - 1 = 31` times. So

```
int t = (data[c] - 128) >> 31; //where t is the sign of data[c] - 128, 0 for positive and 1 for negative
sum += ~t & data[c]; //Add data[c] in sum if t = 0 i.e when the sign of data[c] - 128 is positive
```