# What do the & and | operators do? How are they different from && and ||? Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, operators

I've seen many instances where `|` or `&`are used, but I haven't understood what they are used for. I know what `&&` and `||` mean, but I would like to know the difference between them and their single character counterparts. Also, it would be great if someone could show me examples of where `|` and `&` are used (in Swift 2 please). Thank you

Comment: These are bitwise AND and bitwise OR. For some uses see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883384/practical-applications-of-bitwise-operations

Comment: I didn't really understand much in that post. I've seen the `|` operator used in swift in sprite kit, like so `body.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = someBody | otherBody`. What does this mean?

Comment: Read about bitwise operator in Swift [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html).

Comment: Thank you! That helped clear things up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Wikipedia page on Bitwise Operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) and the [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html) for bitwise operators.

These are bitwise operators. `&` is bitwise AND and `|` is bitwise OR.

See these examples:

```
    0011 (decimal 3)
AND 0010 (decimal 2)
  = 0010 (decimal 2)

   0101 (decimal 5)
OR 0011 (decimal 3)
 = 0111 (decimal 7)
```

> Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

The uses of bitwise operators have been discussed before on StackOverflow:

- [practical applications of bitwise operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883384/practical-applications-of-bitwise-operations)
- [Using bitwise operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353143/using-bitwise-operations)

A use of bitwise XOR (not in your question, but a cool logic gate anyway) that caught my eye (by @Vilx- [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3883616/2773311)) <s>(I don't know how it works, but the answer was accepted and up-voted 34 times)</s>

**EDIT:** If you want to know how it works, there's a nice simple proof over on [XOR swap algorithm - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)

> Swapping two integer variables without an intermediary variable:

```
A = A^B // A is now XOR of A and B
B = A^B // B is now the original A
A = A^B // A is now the original B
```

If these don't help, the Wikipedia page I already linked to twice in this post has an [Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Applications) section, but they don't really apply to higher-level languages (unless for some reason you want to optimize your arithmetic to use only bitwise operations).

Comment: So the bitwise AND operator is basically like the ∩ (intersect) symbol for set notation in maths, and the bitwise OR operator is like the ∪ (union) symbol for set notation right? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, **_if_** your sets are composed of a `1` when the bit is 1 and the empty set when the bit is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can read about them and their differences in Swift docs.

> **Logical Operators** [<sup>1</sup>](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID60)
>
> Logical operators modify or combine the Boolean logic values true and
>   false. Swift supports the three standard logical operators found in
>   C-based languages:
>
> ```
> Logical NOT (!a)
>
> Logical AND (a && b)
>
> Logical OR (a || b)
> ```

> **Bitwise Operators** [<sup>2</sup>](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html)
>
> Bitwise operators enable you to manipulate the individual raw data
>   bits within a data structure. They are often used in low-level
>   programming, such as graphics programming and device driver creation.
>   Bitwise operators can also be useful when you work with raw data from
>   external sources, such as encoding and decoding data for communication
>   over a custom protocol.
>
> Swift supports all of the bitwise operators found in C, as described
>   below.

Answer (score 1):

`&` and `|` are bitwise operators that is they compare the bit representation(binary value).

```
`&` -bitwise AND operator
`|` -bitwise OR operator
```

`&&` and `||` are used to compare the actual values in case of primitives like `int,double,etc.` and the address in case of objects.They are called logical operators.

```
 1. Lets go to an example to make it simpler (bitwise operator):



    int p=9; int q=10;
    //binary representation of 9 and 10 are 1001 and 1010 respectively.
```

- Now, `p & q` returns a one in each bit position for which the
  corresponding bits of both operands are ones.
- `p|q` returns a one in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of either or both operands are ones.

  ```
   2.An example for logical operators.
   int p=9; int q=10;
  ```
- `p>0 && q>0` returns true since `p` and `q` are both greater than `0`(since the conditions on either side of the operator is true).
- `p>0 || q<0` returns true since at least one condition is true(here,p is greater than 0).

I hope that this has helped you to understand the difference between `bitwise` and `logical` operators.